# def __str__(self) issue - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, string, django-models

I'm trying to print the title of the first object in my DB in django. However, when I enter the command

`Project.objects.all()` in the shell, it just returns the following:

`<QuerySet [<Project: Project object (1)>]>`

This is my code:

```
# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    progress = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Task(models.Model):
    
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    priority = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    open_date = models.DateTimeField()
    close_date = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The **str** part doesn't seem to be doing anything, even when I purposely misspell something, no error is returned. There seems to be a few threads with similar issues with no accepted solutions as of yet.

I would like it to return the title that I've entered, which should be <QuerySet [<Project: My First Project>]>.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did it look right when you extracted the project instance from the QuerySet?

Comment: Yep. I created another object which was updated in the query set. I checked my models.py file for any errors and this is what i found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120707/defining-django-settings-module

Answer (score 1):

You are passing self.title to the **str** method. Just pass self and then return the title.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've just changed it but it's still returning the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the `repr` of underlying objects is used when printing their containers (all the built-in collections types do this for instance). Change the name of the method from `__str__` to `__repr__` and it should fix your issue. `__str__` already defaults to using the `__repr__` method if no other `__str__` is defined, so it'll still work in other stringifying scenarios.