# Defining DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I checked my models.py file for any errors by using the command `python models.py check` and it returned the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, 
but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

So I entered the command:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project1.settings`

where project1 is the folder directory that contains the settings.py file. I've also tried replacing "project1" with the name of my virtual environment "bugstracker". Both attempts returned the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project1'`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bugstracker'`

What am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't run the `models.py` directly. Run `python manage.py check` instead. The `manage.py` script takes care of setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` for you.

Comment: thanks. no issues found when i do that